# Socket.io proxy through Apache and its performance

Tags: apache-2.4, node.js, websocket, socket.io

I am trying to setup a server for a Socket.IO game, but we will also have a little landing page in php served through Apache.

I managed to make the server work by doing a proxy from Apache to the Socket.IO app. Apache is running on :80 and node on :8080, which will be closed to the public. The proxy is done on a subdirectory from apache. The configuration is as follows:

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
LoadModule proxy_wstunnel_module modules/mod_proxy_wstunnel.so

    ServerAdmin XXXXX
    ServerName XXXXX
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/XXXXX
    ErrorLog /var/log/error.log
    CustomLog /var/log/access.log combined
    SSLCertificateFile XXXXX
    SSLCertificateKeyFile XXXXX
    Include XXXXX
    SSLCertificateChainFile XXXXX

    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  ^/socket.io            [NC]
    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} transport=websocket    [NC]
    RewriteRule /(.*)           ws://localhost:8080/$1 [P,L]


    ProxyRequests Off
    ProxyPreserveHost On
    ProxyVia Full
    <Proxy *>
        Require all granted
    </Proxy>

    ProxyPass /game http://localhost:8080 retry=0
    ProxyPassReverse /game http://localhost:8080
    ProxyPass        /socket.io http://localhost:8080/socket.io
    ProxyPassReverse /socket.io http://localhost:8080/socket.io

</VirtualHost>
</IfModule>
```

Now, my question is as follows:
Will this affect performance, and is it possible that the rewrite rule for apache will be too much for it to handle for, let's say, at most *maybe* 10k players?

If it might, is there another better choice for the configuration?